# about sql select not working

Tags: sql, database, select

I've got some code

```
select id_towaru, nazwa_tow from TOWAR where ID_KATEGORIA = '00001'
```

i want to see new column near `nazwa_tow`, and in this column called (result) I've got string: it's work'.

how use this only with select ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT id_towaru, nazwa_tow, 'it''s work' AS result
FROM TOWAR
WHERE ID_KATEGORIA = '00001'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT id_towaru, nazwa_tow, 'it''s work' AS result
FROM TOWAR
WHERE ID_KATEGORIA = '00001'
```

or

```
SELECT id_towaru, nazwa_tow, 'it''s work' [result]
FROM TOWAR
WHERE ID_KATEGORIA = '00001'
```